# Centering of the image in php gd library

Tags: php, html

Hey all I am planning to create an image using gd library in php.. I have done that well .. But I need to place the image in the center of the browser. For me the image is appearing on the side instead of the center..

My Image link

```
    http://postimg.org/image/fmax3yrnt/
```

My code..

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/png");

$im = @imagecreate(800, 600)

or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xDD);

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 133, 14, 91);


imagestring($im, 5, 300, 300,  "I'm a pretty picture:))", $text_color);

imagepng($im);


imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

I need to add the produced image to the center of the browser instead of having it appear on the side ...Hope you guys can help me out ..Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks ..

Comment: Can't you use some CSS to center the image? It isn't special just because it is generated in PHP.

Comment: what can i do if the image is generated by the user like $_POST['image'] ..how can i add the link in src if the image is randomly generated ??

Comment: What @JohnConde said - try googling "center image css". There are about a dozen different ways of doing this.

Comment: The PHP fragment you've given returns an image. To the browser, it's an image. It doesn't matter that the URL doesn't end in `png` - the content type tells the browser it's an image. Just use `<img src="...url to PHP code that generates image..." />` and style it the way you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the image to an HTML tag:

```
<img src="http://postimg.org/image/fmax3yrnt/" />
```

And then style it to display however you want.

Comment: what can i do if the image is generated by the user like $_POST['image'] ..how can i add the link in src if the image is randomly generated ??

Comment: @user3583735 then the `src` attribute would point to the file outputting the image, for example: `<img src="path/to/script.php" />`

Comment: see my image was randomly generated like imagecreate() ..so i dont have the path of the image ..to apply it on src ..

Comment: i dont have the adress here ..i just have a randomly created image ...create using imagecreatefunction() so do i need to use the php file name on src ??

Comment: @user3583735 yes, the script that contains `imagecreate` is the same script that outputs the image, therefore that is the address to put in the `src`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing code, I don't see how you generated this image with that code (Unless I'm missing something?!?)

http://s12.postimg.org/ews4rlr4b/Capture.png (which was the primary image on http://postimg.org/image/fmax3yrnt/

You didn't use $background_color anywhere that I see.

That being said, the problem is you are setting the canvas size of the image to be 800x600, and the box you created was less than that size.  You either need to scale that box up, or create $im at the size you intend to make the colored box.  Once you do that the white space will disappear and the image will center properly